# Trying to check if string contains special characters or lowercase java

Tags: java, regex, string, object

I'm trying to get this regex lines to work but they don't seem to be working (I can't get it print out "matches".

My goal is to read in a string from Scanner and then run this function. If the string has either lower case values OR special characters then I want to call the invalid function and then return NULL. Then in the isValid() method, I'll have it return false and end.

if it contains NUMBERS and UPPERCASE characters only i want to return the string as it is so it can do other things.

I can't seem to get it print out "matches". I'm sure I'm doing this right and it's really frustrating me, I've been checking the forums for different ways but none seem to work.

Thanks for the help.

```
  public static String clean(String str){

    String regex = "a-z~@#$%^&*:;<>.,/}{+";
    if (str.matches("[" + regex + "]+")){
        printInvalidString(str);
        System.out.println("matches");
    } else{
        return str;
    }

    return null;
}

public static boolean isValid(String validationString){

    //clean the string
    validationString = clean(validationString);
    if (validationString == null){
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches` will try matching from `start` of string.If at the `start` there is not `lowercase` or `Special characters` it will `fail`.Use `.find` or simply make positive assertion.

```
^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

If this `passes` with `matches` its a valid string for you.

Comment: I think another issue is that character `^` must be escaped even between brackets

Comment: @Pablo it's not necessary unless it's the first character.

Answer (score 3):

To match numbers and upper case characters only use:

```
^[\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]+$

`^`      ... Assert position is at the beginning of the string.
`[`      ... Start of the character class
`\p{Lu}` ... Match an "uppercase letter"
`\p{Nd}` ... Match a "decimal digit"
`]`      ... End of the character class
`+`      ... Match between 1 and unlimited times.
`$`      ... Assert position is at the end of the string.
```

---

The escaped java string version
of: `a-z~@#$%^&*:;<>.,/}{+`
is: `"a-z~@#\\$%\\^&\\*:;<>\\.,/}\\{\\+"`

Answer (score 1):

beside checking the string with long pattern you can check it if contain uppercase or numbers i rewrite the function in this way:

```
 public static String clean(String str) {

    //String regex = "a-z~@#$%^&*:;<>.,/}{+";
    Pattern regex=Pattern.compile("[^A-Z0-9]");
    if (str.matches(".*" + regex + ".*")) {
        printInvalidString(str);
        System.out.println("matches");
    } else {
        return str;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your regex will match a string that **only** has invalid characters. So a string with valid and invalid characters will not match the regex.

Validating the strings would be easier:

```
if (str.matches([\\dA-Z]+)) return str;
else printInvalidString(str);
```